# how to store multiple selected listbox items in a session and view on another form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, string, session

The thing I want to do is that i want to select 1,2 or 3 items from the listbox and save them into a session and then display them all on another form in a listbox.

Here's my code!
This is my first post on stack overflow, so no hate please <3

```
    //WebForm1

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lstProducts.Items.Add("Soap");
            lstProducts.Items.Add("Schampoo");
            lstProducts.Items.Add("Conditioner");
        }
    }

    protected void cmdBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string[] products = new string[3];

            for (int i = 0; i < lstProducts.Items.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (lstProducts.Items[i].Selected)
                    products[i] = lstProducts.Items[i].Text;
                else
                    products[i] = "0";
            }

            Session["Cart"] = products;

    }

    protected void cmdCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Cart"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
        }
    }
}


    //WebForm2


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] products = (string[])Session["Cart"];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            if (products[i] != "0")
            {
                lstCart.Items.Add(products[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The thing is that I only get the last selected item to display in the listbox on form2???

Answer (score 0):

Try this

To store all items of the of the list box, you can add that items in array as:

```
string[] a = new string[]{"item 1","item 2","item 3"};
Session["values"] = a;
```

And in the next page, you can retrieve it like this.

```
string[] a = (string[])Session["values"]
```

EDIT #1

your case you can do like

```
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                al.Add(ListBox1.Items[i].Value);
            }
        }
        Session["selectedValues"] = al;
```

now you can use this sessiom variable in another page, but don't forget to cast in ArrayList type of object.

Comment: But I want to store only multiple lstProducts.SelectedItem in the session, not all the items in the listbox?

Comment: use a loop from 0 to list.items.count and if the item is selected add that to string array and then add that array to session.

Comment: are you using listbox tool of asp.net

Comment: asp:ListBox?
I just want to select multiple items from a listbox, store them into a session and display on another form in a listbox.

Comment: see my updated answer now.it is working. use arraylist instead of string array.

Comment: where you are facing problem ?

Comment: I am facing problem on WebForm2 to get the values from al to listbox

Comment: ArrayList al = ((ArrayList)Session["Cart"]);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (al != null)
                {
                    lstCart.Items.Add(al[i].ToString());
                }